# Execute 'onscroll' function only once

Tags: javascript, function, chart.js, dom-events, onscroll

SEE - https://codepen.io/pranavraghaw1/pen/BaNGRXY

I'm using the onscroll event in Javascript to animate my chart, made using 'Chart.js'.

The problem is, The function gets called every time I scroll on the page.

The approach that I'm using to calculate the Position of Display(the X-position when the graph-animation will run) is :

[image: Simple approach to call functions on scroll]

One solution that I tried (for execting the function only once) is :

```js
let run = true;  
 if (Ypos>play && run) {
   run = false;
   disp();
 }
```

SEE - https://codepen.io/pranavraghaw1/pen/BaNGRXY

> I'm not experience in jQuery, so I'll need a solution in Javascript
>   only.

Comment: your problem is here `let run = true;  ` this should be declared outside your ´addEventListener´ not inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is here `let run = true;` this should be declared outside your´addEventListener´ not inside.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Though I still don't how replacing the code worked, but thanx man.